# How to generate a list of lists with random numbers of the same length

Tags: python, list, random

How do you generate a random list of lists? I can generate a random list using the following `[random.sample(range(80), 20)]`.

You can use the `*` function to make it list of lists but the numbers aren't random for each list. I can find answers relating to the creation of random list of lists that produce variable lengths but I can't find anything that will produce random numbers with the same length.

Comment: If you want to generate that sample multiple times, perhaps what you want is `[random.sample(range(80), 20) for _ in range(number_of_samples)]` This actually runs `random.sample` multiple times whereas `*` would take the result and just duplicate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way, assuming that you want several random samples of the same kind.

First, for neatness, not necessity, *curry* `random.sample` using `functools partial` so that it produces, for the sake of this example, a sample of size 5 from the integers from 0 through 9 inclusive, each time it's called.

Then simply use list comprehension to produce a collection of those samples.

```
>>> import random
>>> from functools import partial
>>> one_sample = partial(random.sample, range(10), 5)
>>> one_sample()
[2, 8, 0, 5, 6]
>>> sample = [one_sample() for _ in range(3)]
>>> sample
[[9, 6, 7, 2, 0], [5, 8, 9, 6, 7], [5, 0, 6, 7, 3]]
```